# How to initialize an array of container maps in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, containers

How to initialize an array of container maps in Matlab? Is there any structure provided for doing so?

I need something like refMap(1) up to refMap(n). Each a a unique dictionary.

I intend to use it to translate a global reference to a local reference. I'm working with a sort of a parallel programming code. So I cannot simply place all my information on the same map. I'll ended up with a structure as slow as it can be.

Comment: No. Why do you need an array of `container.Map` objects? Why not just put everything in a `container.Map` since it's.... a container.

Comment: That would not be possible. I intend to use it to translate a global reference to a local reference. I'm working with a sort of a parallel programming code. I'll ended up with a structure as slow as it can be.

Comment: I need to hold multiple maps that need to be accessed such as map{3} map(4) or in a similar way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just storing them within a cell array and then you can write a little anonymous function to create all of them

```
create_containers = @(n)arrayfun(@(x)containers.Map(), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

And then use it to create `N` containers.Map` objects

```
containers = create_containers(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can use an array. I would put the different container maps into cells.

```
mapObj_1 = containers.Map(Set_11, Set_12);
cellObjs = {mapObj_1, mapObj_2, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an indirect way to do so. I can define a class which a container maps is a property of it. So instead of initializing an array of container maps I simply initialize an array of objects with containers inside of it.

This sets a class of dict that has a container map trans inside of it.

```
classdef dict      
    properties
        trans = containers.Map           
    end
    methods
    end        
end
```

This initialize 4 objects

```
for ii = 1:4
    op(ii) = dict();
end
```

Now, you can use them by simply calling
op(ii).trans

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old thread, I would like to suggest my answer. You could use a cell array of maps.

```
no_of_maps = 10;

map1 = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
c = {cluster1};
for i = 2:1:no_of_maps
    c{i} = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
end
```

Now you got an array of maps each of which you could access as c{i}. Please edit the 'KeyType' and 'ValueType' parameters as needed.